# Conditional Left Join

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to return columns only when needed.

Data will only exists in the `1_finance_add_details` and the addresses `e` tables when `t.trans_type=2`

```
SELECT t.*,
 a.company,
 a.house_number,
 a.flat_number,
 a.house_name,
 a.address1,
 a.address2,
 a.address3,
 a.town,
 a.county,
 a.post_code,
 a.country,
 f.*,
 e.company,
 e.house_number,
 e.flat_number,
 e.house_name,
 e.address1,
 e.address2,
 e.address3,
 e.town,
 e.county,
 e.post_code,
 e.country 
FROM 1_transactions t 
LEFT JOIN addresses a ON a.id=t.fk_addresses_id 
LEFT JOIN 1_finance_add_details f ON t.id=f.fk_transactions_id 
LEFT JOIN addresses e ON e.id=f.employ_fk_addresses_id 
WHERE trans_location=1 AND t.id=19;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the result that you want, but you can just add another condition in your left join like this:

```
FROM 1_transactions t 
LEFT JOIN addresses a ON a.id=t.fk_addresses_id 
LEFT JOIN 1_finance_add_details f ON t.id=f.fk_transactions_id 
LEFT JOIN addresses e ON e.id=f.employ_fk_addresses_id AND t.trans_type=2
WHERE trans_location=1 AND t.id=19;
```

Note: this would render the field of addresses e NULL on every t with type != 2.

Comment: Not quite, I was trying to get the data back with only the columns required and nothing else.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean there, perhaps it'll clarify your question better if you provide like a mock output that you expect from your query.